# How to funcanimation seaborn's lmplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

(*This is an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466462/how-to-create-indefinite-funcanimation-frames-dynamically-updating-in-real-time/51469764#51469764) question*)

Hi

I am trying to update lmplot with new data but unable to find a way to hook it up to existing figure/axes since they have their own.  I have tried so far like this:

```
%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

#fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(5,4))

df = get_data()
g = sns.lmplot( x='Mean', y='Variance', data=df, fit_reg=False, hue='Size', legend=False, palette=cmap)

def get_data():
    takeRandomSample(population, popSize, popVar)   
    current_elem = len(sampleStats)-1
    current_size = sampleStats[current_elem][0]
    current_mean = sampleStats[current_elem][1]
    current_var =  sampleStats[current_elem][2]

    data = {'Size' : current_size, 'Mean' : current_mean, 'Variance' : current_var}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])

    return df


def prep_axes(g):
    g.set(xlim=(0, 20), ylim=(0, 100), xticks=range(0,21))    

    ax = g.axes[0,0]       
    ax.axvline(x=popMean, color='#8c8ca0', ls='dashed')
    ax.axhline(y=popVar, color='#8c8ca0', ls='dashed')
    ax.set_title('Sample Statistics :{}'.format(i))
    ax.set_facecolor(backgroundColour)

def animate(i):
    df = get_data()
    g = sns.lmplot( x='Mean', y='Variance', data=df, fit_reg=False, hue='Size', legend=False, palette=cmap)
    prep_axes(g, i)


# initialize samples
sampleStats = []

plt.tight_layout()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(g.fig, animate, frames = np.arange(1,100), interval=100)
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Problems:**
1. This just produces one static graph, because I Could not find a way to update existing g, and re plot on same g's figure, the lmsplot. animate function is creating new g
2. I had to initialize unnecessarily once to get g object to pass on g.fig to funcanimation which anyway did not help due to point 1 as well.

How do we animate using lmplot? I want to use this instead of regular matplotlib due to hue feature.

I tried using facetgrid directly as well (and pass on lmplot in g.map), but that did not help either.

Comment: Using `funcanimation` in conjunction with `lmplot` would be difficult, and probably conterproductive. However, it seems you are not using any of the features of lmplot (no regression, no facets) only `hue`? It would be much easier to separate your hue categories yourself, or maybe consider using the new [`seaborn.scatterplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot). If you want more help, you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Kindly find it [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/parthi2929/d85e691099d79f9e96e91163acba9e40)  Its the notebook with all snippets. I am stuck at last part. Now I am getting individual static graphs, instead of animation due to separate ```g``` updates every time. Kindly help

Answer (score 3):

For the record, here is how you could animate an `lmplot()`, provided you don't have any facets and you don't care about regressions:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker", data=tips, fit_reg=False)
fig = g.fig
ax = g.axes[0,0]
scatters = [c for c in ax.collections if isinstance(c, matplotlib.collections.PathCollection)]
txt = ax.text(0.1,0.9,'frame=0', transform=ax.transAxes)

def animate(i):
    for c in scatters:
        # do whatever do get the new data to plot
        x = np.random.random(size=(50,1))*50
        y = np.random.random(size=(50,1))*10
        xy = np.hstack([x,y])
        # update PathCollection offsets
        c.set_offsets(xy)
    txt.set_text('frame={:d}'.format(i))
    return scatters+[txt]

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=10, blit=True)
```

[image]

**However in this case, you can obtain almost exactly the same result, in a much more straightforward way, by not using lmplot altogether:**

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatters = []
for g,d in tips.groupby('smoker'):
    s = ax.scatter(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, label=g)
    scatters.append(s)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.,1.), loc=1)
txt = ax.text(0.1,0.9,'frame=0', transform=ax.transAxes)

def animate(i):
    for c in scatters:
        x = np.random.random(size=(50,1))*50
        y = np.random.random(size=(50,1))*10
        xy = np.hstack([x,y])
        c.set_offsets(xy)
    txt.set_text('frame={:d}'.format(i))
    return scatters+[txt]

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=10, blit=True)
```

[image]

From the code above, it is fairly simple to append new values to the previous data, instead of replacing all the points:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatters = []
for g,d in tips.groupby('smoker'):
    s = ax.scatter([], [], label=g)
    scatters.append(s)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.,1.), loc=1)
txt = ax.text(0.1,0.9,'frame=0', transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.set_xlim((0,60))
ax.set_ylim((0,15))

def animate(i, df, x, y, hue):
    new_data = df.sample(20) # get new data here
    for c,(groupname,subgroup) in zip(scatters,new_data.groupby(hue)):
        xy = c.get_offsets()
        xy = np.append(xy,subgroup[[x,y]].values, axis=0)
        c.set_offsets(xy)
    txt.set_text('frame={:d}'.format(i))
    return scatters+[txt]

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(tips, "total_bill", "tip", 'smoker'), frames=10, blit=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Surely will try using matplotlib itself but want to wrap these up as fast as possible. With your seaborn example, almost worked except minor glitches. Matplotlib not seem to be spacing properly the title, it gets cut. More importantly, frames are redrawn, so earlier frame points not retained. My updated code [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/parthi2929/d85e691099d79f9e96e91163acba9e40), output screenshot [here](https://s22.postimg.cc/se3vd9npt/image.png), desired effect [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/unbiased-estimate-of-population-variance/1169428428)

Comment: as per my understanding, we are grabbing the current data point handle and just offsetting it to new position as per new data every frame. Instead, we need to retain old data points of past frames, and for new frame, add new data point on same axes. kind of dynamic scatter plot.

Comment: I've amended my answer above

Comment: thank you very much. can you kindly provide in lmplot, as i expect further usecases , so having lmplot solution as well would be highly helpful.